# How to make pig abort after a certain number of warnings?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I just had a job terminate with this `stdout`:

```
Success!
...
Input(s):
Successfully read 14982562 records from: "..."
Successfully read 21532901 records from: "..."
Successfully read 9322681 records from: "..."

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "..."
Successfully stored 0 records in: "..."
...
2013-11-14 22:50:46,179 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Encountered Warning TOO_LARGE_FOR_INT 7 time(s).
2013-11-14 22:50:46,180 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Encountered Warning ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FIELD 9322681 time(s).
2013-11-14 22:50:46,180 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Encountered Warning FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED 61711157 time(s).
2013-11-14 22:50:46,180 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
```

Obviously, I did something wrong, but instead of telling me what, pig
counted 70M+ warnings and claimed success.

Clearly one cannot store detailed logs for 70M warnings, but claiming success in
such a situation is absurd.

Is there a way to configure it to report every warning in excruciating
detail (which field in which script line for
`ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FIELD`, which field, which value, which type,
which script line for `FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED`) for the
first, say, 10 or 100 or 1000 warnings of each type on each host and then abort?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to abort after X warnings?

I don't think so. The reason is that the UDF you are using thinks it is acceptable to skip over these errors. You could create your own UDF based on the UDF that you are using, and throw an exception instead of a warning upon an error. See [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/seattlehadoop/intro-to-pig-udf) for more details (slide 15).

Are you using HBaseStorage? If so, this other [SO overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480788/loading-hbase-table-with-pig-float-gives-field-discarded-type-conversion-failed) could help you solve this problem. Quick summary: use `HBaseBinaryConverter`.

> Is there a way to configure it to report every warning in excruciating detail [...]?

Yes, you can take a look at each warning independently. See this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510848/pig-non-aggregated-warnings-output-location) for details on how to do this. Quick summary: parse the logs yourself and look for the WARN messages.